# cannot init a class object-Objective C

Tags: objective-c

I need to call a method that has been defined in the same class.I am calling the method initiateSession from the function A.

```
-(BOOL)intitiateSession
{
 //stmts
 return YES;
}
-(BOOL)A
{
 if([self initiateSession])
 {
  //stmts
 }
 return YES;
}
```

getting a runtime error as,

Terminating app due to uncaught exception

> cannot init a class object

### EDITED:

```
@implementation Data
-(BOOL)initiateSession
{
NSLog(@"I am into the initiateSession!!");
return YES;
}
-(BOOL)getNHPData{
        NSLog(@"In getNHPData!!");
        if([self initiateSession])
                   {
                       NSLog(@"I am into the session");
                   }
     return YES;
}
@end
```

Here in the if loop i will call the function.Execute the function and if the function

executes to true i'm getting inside the scope.I could not able to call one function from

other function.

Comment: please post your complete methods

Comment: The only place you should be calling `self = [super init]` is inside your `init` method.

Comment: @Terry Wilcox:You are right.How do i call a function from other function that is defined in the same class?I am getting runtime exceptions when tried with the above invocations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`getNHPData()` is not an initializer and should not be calling `[super init]`. That is something you would call from within your own initializer. Your code as written will not even compile (your `@implementation` line is incorrect). You are certainly receiving many warnings in the above code that you should be listening to (you're returning `self` from a BOOL method in one case, and have no `return` in the other case). Your actual error suggests you're doing something like `[Data getNHPData]` which is not legal since `getNHPData` is an instance method. You should be getting warnings about that as well.

First, clean up all your warnings. That will probably get you moving in the right direction.
Cocoadevcentral has a [quick intro](http://cocoadevcentral.com/d/learn_objectivec/) to all the issues you're running into.

Comment: I debugged the errors as you have pointed out here.Thanks for making me to understand the mistakes i have done in my code.I was breaking my head for 3 hours yesterday.Today it was within 10 minutes i could able to resolve all my errors and warnings.Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You need to call `[super init]` in your overwrite of `-(id) init`.

See #3 and #6 [here](http://cocoadevcentral.com/d/learn_objectivec/).

Answer (score 1):

Always do a `super init` call, when you override `init` in your class.